# Villager Anger Particles outside of village

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Do the anger particles from hitting a villager show up outside a village? If not, then why did the villager I hit have anger particles in my house with no doors?

Comment: Apparently they do. What test would you expect someone to do to verify it? Basically the same as you did.

Comment: The reason I ask is I’m also having problems with a villager breeder at the same time so I thought maybe the village had expanded to include my house and that’s why it wasn’t working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I loaded a blank super flat world, spawned a villager, and punched him several times:
[image: Punched]

Then I created a village and punched him:
[image: Punched 2]

The answer is not absolute, but it seems they only show up when in a village.

As to your house, I suspect it is within 32 blocks of your breeder or another village.